# How to override default template files of a view

Tags: views, theming

I have to implement my custom markup in a view. How I can override the markup for the views header, footer, and attachments? Which TPL files I have to modify and how will be its machine names. Which also respects keeping the templates of the other views unchangeched.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a view called `foobar` than you can create this tpl file in your templates/views directory:

`views-view--foobar.tpl.php`

Then change `foobar` to whatever your view is called and then clear the cache.

To create custom variables to your view create a `hook_preprocess_views_view` in your template.php file, like this:

```
function template_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  $view = $vars['view'];
  $vars['foobar'] = 'Hello World';
}
```

Now you have a `$foobar` variable in your template.

Comment: its okay but where i can find code of my view 'variables etc' to print in my tpl

Comment: You shall put that in a preproces hook in your template.php file there are lots of tutorials on the web

Comment: Did you find something useful if not I can write an answer later

Comment: not i have not fond something useful..

Comment: I have updated my code and now it shall work.

Comment: You need to dump out or inspect variables with a debugger to know what it contains.

Comment: Like `dpm($vars);`?

Answer (score -1):

To override a view you need to write three template files. Below are the files:

1. views-view--search-page.html
2. views-view-unformatted--search-page.html
3. views-view-fields--search-page.html

To know exact names of template files, you can even use Devel module to find out the suggested names.

Location of these files will be : \themes\bootstrap\templates\views\ [place-your-files-here]

After you create your files, clear drupal cache for the code in twigs to be reflected.

Comment: There is no bootstrap theme installed in my site.

Comment: You can place the template files in whatever theme you are using for your project. 

\themes\ [your-theme]\templates\views\ [place-your-files-here]